# How can I add the border to whole vertical th line in Bootsrap table?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap and I made the table like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiPOW.png)

I want to add the vertical red line like the following photo.
Also I want to add drop shadow with red line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1EcH.png)

How can I implement this?

Current code

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drop shadow will be tricky, since a box shadow encompasses an entire element, not just selected sides of table cells as shown here.
But this code should work for your border:
https://codepen.io/richiegarcia/pen/abjOXwB

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0 #333;
}
td, th {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 10%;
}
th:last-child {
    border-top: 5px solid red;
}
th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0 #333;
}
td:last-child {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 0 0 #333;
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 #333;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 #333;
}
```

Comment: thank you. red line works! maybe impossible to implement drop-shadow?

Comment: I updated the answer. With the creative use of box-shadow, the above solution could work.

Comment: @lion-react Please mark this as the correct answer if you're satisfied. Thanks!